# Unity reticle as a pointer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 3d Unity game with few 3d objects in worldspace. I have a reticle in cameraspace. When reticle crosses each 3d object, I have a pointer -enter and pointer-exit event written. when mobile phone is moved the reticle moves, but the 3d object stays in worldspace. The reticle is not functioning as pointer. Although the touch event is working, I could not make reticle as a pointer. I have added physics raycast with the camera.
What mistake I am doing?

Comment: Do you mind posting your current raycast code?

Comment: i have added physics raycast with main camera and therefore have added event triggers for pointer enter and exit. therefore have not written anycode  plz correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Gotcha, which unity version?

Comment: 5.3.4  windows 64 bit

Comment: I'm assuming you have the screen point of the reticle?

Comment: i hv placed reticle at (0,0,0) in screenspace camera. while previewing the reticle does cross the 3d objects but not firing pointer events. but when i touch it triggers events. i want this happen without touching only by shooting rays...

Comment: I have answered the question (with implementation) below. Let me know if you have any questions or concerns!

Comment: thank you so much for your great help....i m just implementing....will let you know asap...just i m getting a warning " use the new keyword  if hiding inherited camera is intended..." and not working....I m just trying...

Comment: Okay, this was tested and works as-is (using mouse position) in an empty scene where the "CameraPointer.cs" script is attached to the main camera object and the "MyObject.cs" script is attached to multiple cubes.

If you don't want the "CameraPointer.cs" to be attached to the camera, you will want to remove `[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]`, `camera = GetComponent<Camera>();`, and replace `camera` with `Camera.main`

Comment: i m accepting as answer....is it possible to hv ur unitypackage file...if u dont mind...

Comment: dont knw what mistake i m doing.....should i remove physics raycast or...should i attach any pointer image??

Comment: No problem [here you go](http://host-a.net/u/grantmooney/ReticlePointer.unitypackage)

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to remove the physics raycast from your camera object

Comment: thanku so much....dont know....how to thank for helping a stranger....hats off to u.....god bless

Comment: no problem, just pay it forward!

Comment: sure....will do for as many as I can

Comment: Just only one doubt....in my scene the reticle is always going to be at (0,0,0)should I change reticlePosition = Input.mousePosition; to anything else? thanks in advance

Comment: That depends where the reticle is in your window. If you take a look at [the mouse position](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html), it makes sure to add that _The bottom-left of the screen or window is at (0, 0). The top-right of the screen or window is at (Screen.width, Screen.height)._ So if you want your reticle to be centered, you can leave it at (Screen.width/2, Screen.height/2, 0)

Comment: many thanks. i understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so you are trying to use a [UI.Selectable](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.html) event (Selectable.OnPointerEnter) on a non-UI object.

Assuming you have the reticle position in screen space, I highly recommend using [Physics.Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) from the a script attached to the Camera object, though it could simply reference the camera instance instead. We can use this combined with a "hitObject" to trigger custom reticle enter/exit/hover events as seen below:

**CameraPointer.cs:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class CameraPointer : MonoBehaviour {
    private GameObject hitObject = null;
    private Vector3 reticlePosition = Vector3.zero;
    private Camera camera;

    void Awake() {
        camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        // TODO: Replace with reticle screen position
        reticlePosition = Input.mousePosition;

        // Raycast variables
        Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(reticlePosition); 
        RaycastHit hit;

        // Raycast
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
            if (hitObject != hit.transform.gameObject) {
                if (hitObject != null) {
                    hitObject.SendMessage("OnReticleExit"); // Trigger "OnReticleExit"
                }
                hitObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
                hitObject.SendMessage("OnReticleEnter"); // Trigger "OnReticleEnter"
            } else {
                hitObject.SendMessage("OnReticleHover"); // Trigger "OnReticleHover"
            }
        } else {
            if (hitObject != null) {
                hitObject.SendMessage("OnReticleExit"); // Trigger "OnReticleExit"
            }
            hitObject = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**MyObject.cs:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MyObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Custom reticle events
    void OnReticleEnter()
    {
        Debug.Log("Entering over " + this.name);
    }
    void OnReticleExit()
    {
        Debug.Log("Exiting over "+this.name);
    }
    void OnReticleHover()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hovering over "+this.name);
    }
}
```